# Syncing Data Items between Mobile Device and Wear

Tags: android

I am trying to sync Data between my Mobile Device and my Wear. But without any success. I did everything [from the developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html) I think.

This is the MainActivity of my mobile Code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataMapRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    private static final String COUNT_KEY = "com.example.torbengab.sendwatchmessage";

    DataClient mDataClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendStuff();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendStuff() {
        mDataClient = Wearable.getDataClient(this);
        PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/message").setUrgent();
        putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt(COUNT_KEY, 123);
        PutDataRequest putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest().setUrgent();
        Task<DataItem> putDataTask = mDataClient.putDataItem(putDataReq);

        putDataTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataItem>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DataItem dataItem) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sending :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting the putDataTask.addOnSuccessListener onSuccess callback. So I think this part works fine.
And here is the Wear Project MainActivity:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.wearable.CapabilityClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.CapabilityInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMapItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements DataClient.OnDataChangedListener,
        MessageClient.OnMessageReceivedListener,
        CapabilityClient.OnCapabilityChangedListener {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private static final String COUNT_KEY = "com.example.torbengab.sendwatchmessage";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Instantiates clients without member variables, as clients are inexpensive to create and
        // won't lose their listeners. (They are cached and shared between GoogleApi instances.)
        Wearable.getDataClient(this).addListener(this);
        Wearable.getMessageClient(this).addListener(this);
        Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this)
                .addListener(
                        this, Uri.parse("wear://"), CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Wearable.getDataClient(this).removeListener(this);
        Wearable.getMessageClient(this).removeListener(this);
        Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this).removeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(@NonNull DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yey", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for (DataEvent event : dataEventBuffer) {
            if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                // DataItem changed
                DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
                if (item.getUri().getPath().compareTo("/message") == 0) {
                    DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(dataMap.getInt(COUNT_KEY)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
                // DataItem deleted
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCapabilityChanged(@NonNull CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yey", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yey", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Maybe I have to add permissions to the manifest file, but I found nothing online. It would very cool if one of you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get it working with these 3 steps:

**1. The receiving side implements a CHANGE listener**

Thus `putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt(COUNT_KEY, 123);` works only once.
You need to change the value `123` each time the `sendStuff()` method gets called.

**2. Both modules mobile & wear must have the *very same application id* set in the build.gradle file**

```
    android {
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myapp"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        ...
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

**3. Both modules mobile & wear must have the same signature**

you need to

*a) Generate an upload key and keystore*

- In the menu bar, click Build > Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK.
- In the Generate Signed Bundle or APK dialog, select Android App Bundle or APK and click Next.
- Below the field for Key store path, click Create new.
- On the New Key Store window, provide the information for your keystore and key

*b) Sign your app with your key*

- If you don’t currently have the Generate Signed Bundle or APK dialog open, click Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK.
- In the Generate Signed Bundle or APK dialog, select either Android App Bundle or APK and click Next.
- Select a module from the drop down.
- Specify the path to your keystore, the alias for your key, and enter the passwords for both.

and because the signature gets invalid as soon as the code is changed

*c) Configure the build process to automatically sign your app*

- In the Project window, right click on your app and click Open Module Settings.
- On the Project Structure window, under Modules in the left panel, click the module you would like to sign.
- Click the Signing tab, then click Add .
- Select your keystore file, enter a name for this signing configuration (as you may create more than one), and enter the required information.
- Click the Build Types tab.
- Click the release build.
- Under Signing Config, select the signing configuration you just created.

finally you should

*d) Remove signing information from your build files*

which is very well documented right here (all step a-d):

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing